# How move HTML, transfer code in DOM

Tags: html, google-chrome, move

I need move div into div, but don't copy->remove->paste, don't clone. I need transfer.
The div have a html5 video, and if i clone the video will be reset, the same ocurrs with flash or youtube video.

This:

```
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

In this:

```
<div><div></div></div>
```

Not this:

```
document.getElementById('target').appendChild(  document.getElementById('to_be_moved') )
```

Not this (JQUERY):

```
$("target").insert($("to_be_moved").remove());
```

If dom tags are persons, and DOM is a house, and i want go in real life to other room (Like other place in DOM (My house)), i don't need destroy (Destroing my propertys, events, actual state,...) my body and create in other room, i only walk and transfer my body.

**PLAYGROUND: http://jsfiddle.net/r4RVF/ (Play video and later move)**

Thanks

Comment: [JQuery .appendTo()](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/).

Comment: @Vucko nope. http://jsfiddle.net/r4RVF/

Comment: Inspect the element after clicking the button.

Comment: @Vucko the video is reseted after click. This is because DOM is removed, and later is added. Just this is the problem. Read my first message please.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your `remove()` in the second breaks what you're trying to do. Have you tried just simply

```
$('#to_be_moved').appendTo($('#target'));
```

Comment: Nope, your answer is the same concept. Don't help. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/r4RVF/